# Is there a way to solve "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate" because of having "nan" values in the column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["john","peter","john","peter","peter"],
    "height": ["6","5","4","nan","8"],
})
df
```

I want to do GROUPBY name and AGG the height for mean

```
df2=df.groupby('name')
df3=df2.agg({'height':'mean'})
```

But I get this ERROR
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
I did some search and I applied this one

```
df.height = pd.to_numeric(df.height,errors='ignore')
```

But still the code does not work and I get the same error!

"nan" values were created as a result of some joins that I did on previous dataframes.
Thank you for your time and help.
I will upvote your answers.

Comment: `errors='coerce'`

Comment: Thank you this one worked. If you write it as an answer I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sum() function

```
df2=df.groupby('name').height.sum()
```

I hope you find it helpful